# What if I am trying to clone github private repository over https protocol and my password contains @ character in it?

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I have a private github repository and i can clone the repository by making https request only. SSH is not an option for me.
My command should be like this:

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/asrrepo/QA.git
```

But what if my password starts with **@** character in it?

```
git clone https://username:@password@github.com/asrrepo/QA.git
```

I don't want it to prompt me to enter the password.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `@` with `%40`?

Comment: Yes maybe urlencode (%40) or escape it with a \.

Comment: that works. thanks to you both!

Comment: @ASR You are welcome, and don't forget to mark a answer.

Comment: @Johan, Did that already. BTW how can i mess with Johan. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run 
 `git clone https://username@github.com/asrrepo/QA.git`
 it will prompt for your password

**Update: (if you don't want it to be prompted)**
`https://username:%40password@github.com/asrrepo/QA.git`

Comment: so in that case you should run git clone https://usenrame:%40password....